# Android AppDisplay (GridView& NoSystemApp)

Tags: android, gridview, launcher

I found this tutorial : [Build and Application Launcher with Android](http://code2live.net/?p=177).

The objective is for developing an `applauncher` for my android launcher. Now all works fine when I integrated this code in my launcher.  Now I want to change a few things :

1. First I want that the `applauncher` to only display the apps which are not part of the system like its displayed on normal android.
2. The next thing is that I hate this list view. I would much prefer a grid view but I don't seem to get it right.

Can somebody help me or give good links which explain these things better to me.

Comment: It would be quite helpful if you provided a bit of code you have instead of saying you "didn't quite get it right".  Show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

```
<GridView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/empty"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:text="List PlaceHolder"/>
```

I changed the ListView into the GridView, but now i don't know what i have to change in code. There are Several lists and one of them i habe to change to some grid stuff i think